# Cannot print in while() loop in php ajax

Tags: php, loops, printing, status, flush

I am trying to notify a user, the status of a (another)script the runs in background (it runs once every minute).

So I have this php code:

```
    while(@fopen("dl.conf","r")){ 
      print "Download will start soon";
      flush();
      sleep(1);
    }
    .
    .
```

It doesn't print anything, plus even if I cancel that file it won't execute the rest of the script.

basically a user can submit a file to download. this will trigger the file dl.conf to be created. there is a script running in background checking if dl.conf exists, if so it reads it, and starts the download. It will delete dl.conf file too.

It might happen that the user submit the download but the script will take few more seconds to run again, and realize that there is something to download. so I just want the user to wait for the download which will start very soon (then the download progress will be shown).

thank you

Comment: There's a parse error in your code.

Comment: There is no parse error, I just ran this code and no error is shown

Comment: weird I don't get any parse error. Could you please tell me what the error is?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `fopen()` to check if file is there, you can simply use `file_exists()` like this.

```
// run loop till file exists
while(file_exists("dl.conf")){ 
    print "Download will start soon";
    flush();
    sleep(1);

    // clear stat cache to get correct file status
    clearstatcache();
}
```

You do not need the clearstatcache() call if the background script is also a PHP script and uses `unlink()` to delete the `dl.conf` file. As `unlink()` clears the file stat cache automatically.

**Update**

Sometimes flush() or ob_flush alone do not work. Look at this comment on PHP documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php#90529

So if you are using output_buffering for sure, you can try this set of commands.

```
ob_end_flush(); 
ob_flush(); 
flush(); 
ob_start();
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I get the same behavior this way. Nothing is printed. I cannot use unlink() because this php script is not in charge to delete dl.conf. It doesn't know when to delete it

Comment: If you get no output, it means that `file_exists()` is returning false.  try `var_dump(file_exists("dl.conf"))` just before the while loop to check what is the return value.

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump(file_exists("dl.conf"))`

Comment: boolean true, when the file exists. false otherwise. Anyway I had to remove the while loop in order to print. even if I placed it before the loop.

Comment: If the output is true, then the `while()` loop should run. If it is not executing even once, it means the `dl.conf` file is already deleted by the upload script before the `while()` loop is reached.

Comment: I am quite sure the while() loop runs. in fact when the download starts and the dl.conf is deleted, it actually quits the loop and prints the progress bar as it should. But it stays blank as long as it is in the loop. I am not able yet to display the message

Comment: If you are using output buffering `flush()` alone might not work. You would need to use `ob_flush()`.

Comment: Unfortunately ob_flush() won't help as well

Comment: It just won't work, even with that set of commands. thank you for all the answers but I guess I need to find another way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Well you are blocking the error.

Try this:

```
$fOpen = @fopen("dl.conf","r");

if(!$fOpen) die('ERROR of some kind...');

while($fOpen){ 
  print "Download will start soon";
  flush();
  sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I get the same behavior this way. Nothing is printed.

Comment: @Danny -- do you have php errors and error logging turned on?

Comment: yes, I just checked, I have display_errors and log_errors ON. error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT

Comment: @Danny remove the `@` before the `fopen`

Comment: if I remove @ nothing change. plus,I am noticing that the dl.conf won't be ever deleted this way. It is open and it needs a close()

Answer (score 0):

you'd better to use ajax for this case and also change this 
script which should be handled in ajax onresponse event

```
if(file_exists('dl.conf'))
{
 return 'file created, download will start soon';
}
```

Comment: It is actually handled in ajax I forgot to mention it. This code is part of the script that shows the progress bar. Anyway, I need a cycle or something that won't let the script go on, otherwise it will replace whatever message I write with something else.

Comment: the response will be buffered and wont be sent to output while script is still running, you can try to play with ob_flush() function or related configuration options in php.ini but i think it is not the option

Comment: also possibly this question can be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385676/php-buffered-output-depending-on-server-setting